# Treat multiple lines as one item in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an invoice_detail table that stores all invoice information.  Obviously the detail table stores each line item, to break out the invoice like this:

```
Ticket_Detail_ID   Ticket_Number   Customer_ID   Service_Code  Total
     1                1                 15           Book1       4.00
     2                1                 15           Book2       5.00
     3                1                 15           Book3       6.00
     4                2                 16           Book1       4.00
     5                2                 16           Book2       5.00
     6                3                 17           Book1       4.00
     7                3                 17           Book2       5.00
     8                3                 17           Book3       6.00
```

I want to Select a count of distinct tickets based on Ticket_number That does not have a "Book3"  service code.  So in this example I would count:

`Ticket 16`, since it did not have a "Book3"

It would return:

`1`

My query right now is:

```
Select Count (Distinct Ticket_Number) as Total
From Invoice_Details
Where Service_Code <> 'Book3'
```

This returns:

```
6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Ticket_Number)
FROM dbo.YourTable T
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
                 WHERE Service_Code = 'Book3'
                 AND Ticket_Number = T.Ticket_Number)
```

[**Here is an sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d569a) with a demo of this.